# Use a Username in a Path to Route a Component (React-router-dom)

Tags: react-router-dom

I am having a hard time setting up my react-router so that when the path matches the user's username, the `userProfile` component will be routed and show individually. For example, when the URL is `http://localhost:3000/myusername`, the `userProfile` component will only show. I'm kind of confused on how it will work if someone just pastes the entire link instead of being directed to someone's page through the UI.

```js
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={userProfile} /> 
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/test2" component={test2} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/test3" component={test3} />
</Switch>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method and access to **username** in **test3** component and handle getting data and showing this page

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={userProfile} /> 
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/test2" component={test2} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/:username" component={test3} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: ooooh, I see how it's done, thanks for the help! I ended up using the /:id and useParams to get the url id in the path that would be passed down as a prop and used in a dispatch useEffect function to request the users profile data.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you just use `/:id` in the path, then the path extension will pass automatically down to the `userProfile` component when you use the `const {id} = useParams()` function in the `userProfile` component. Then I passed the `_id` down as a prop from the `userProfile` component to the `Info` component so that it can be used to automatically fetch data in a `useEffect()` and redux `dispatch()` function. Oh and also, the `<Route path="/:id" component={userProfile} />` needs to be an `exact path` and must go to the bottom of the Route Switch list so that it doesn't get picked first.

```js
<Switch>
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/test2" component={test2} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/test3" component={test3} />
    <Route exact path="/:id" component={userProfile} /> 
</Switch>
```

```js
const Profile = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
       <Info _id={id} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

```js
const Info = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProfileInfo(props._id));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div></div>
  );
};

export default Info;
```